# pulling activation function from MLPRegressor object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to do dimensionality reduction using: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/science.pdf

What this does, is create an autoencoder with a middle layer consisting of 2 nodes.

after training, the neural net is "cut in half" and we just forward propagate until we get 2D data.  We can plot that, and do KNN, and other fun stuff

I'm using sklearn, and I can get as far as training the network

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
HLS = (4,2,4)
m_ann = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(HLS), max_iter=10**5, activation='relu')

m_ann.fit(X_train,X_train)
```

and I can get the NN coefficients with `m_ann.coefs_` and `m_ann.intercepts_`

So, I can create a loop that does manual matrix multiplication, addition, then write my own `relu` function and call that.  BUT what I'd like to do is apply whatever activation function my network uses (for example, if a user trains using linear, or sigmoid activation, I don't want them to have to change any code)

Is it possible to get MLPRegressor to apply an activation function to arbitrary data?

Comment: You mean using the predict method as m_ann.predict(X_new)?

Comment: yes, but I want to do it manually, so i can short-circuit at the hidden layer with 2 nodes